# Adding multiple markers after getting response from JSON but application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-volley

I havebeen updating multiple markers on map in my postexecute method, because i need Lat-Lon from json, In this case my application will get hang for 4-5 seconds and sometime shows message

> application not responding

, here is my code-

```
try{
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            jsonObject2=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ViewAgency_Set_Get set_Get = new ViewAgency_Set_Get();
            set_Get.setservices_type(jsonObject2.getString("fld_category_name"));
            set_Get.setCity(jsonObject2.getString("fld_city_name"));
            set_Get.setPincode(jsonObject2.getString("fld_pincode"));
            set_Get.setSalary(jsonObject2.getString("fld_budget"));
            set_Get.setFulltime_preference(jsonObject2.getString("fld_full_time_preference"));
            set_Get.setParttimePreference(jsonObject2.getString("fld_part_time_preference"));
            set_Get.setAvailabiliy(jsonObject2.getString("fld_availability"));
            set_Get.setExperience(jsonObject2.getString("fld_exp_from")+"-"+jsonObject2.getString("fld_exp_to"));
            set_Get.setDate(jsonObject2.getString("fld_posting_date"));
            set_Get.setVendor_worker_id(jsonObject2.getString("fld_post_your_req_id"));
            set_Get.setApply_job("Apply");
            JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("getjobSpecItems");
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray2.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(j);
                Grid_specs grid_specs = set_Get.new Grid_specs();
                grid_specs.setSpeciality(jsonObject3.getString("fld_sub_category_name"));
                set_Get.list_Specs.add(grid_specs);
            }
            arrayList_jobs.add(set_Get);

            final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
            final String zip = jsonObject2.getString("fld_pincode");
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(zip, 1);
            if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
                address = addresses.get(0);
                String message = String.format("Latitude: %f, Longitude: %f",
                        address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude()))
                        .title("Job Posted for:- "+jsonObject2.getString("fld_category_name"));

                // changing marker color
                if (arrayList_jobs.get(i).getservices_type().equals("Tutor")){
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_tutor));
                }
                if (arrayList_jobs.get(i).getservices_type().equals("Maid")){
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_maid));
                }if (arrayList_jobs.get(i).getservices_type().equals("Driver")){
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_driver));
                }if (arrayList_jobs.get(i).getservices_type().contains("Chef")){
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_chef));
                }if (arrayList_jobs.get(i).getservices_type().equals("Helper")){
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_help));
                }
                marker =googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(13).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        SearchJobListAdapter adapter = new SearchJobListAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList_jobs,
                "Show",manager);
        search_listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there 2 main that I see can be improved:

> 1)
>   markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_XXX);

this one takes a lot of time and you do it many times

Solution is to create all the Bitmap for markers when u initialize the activity for example. if they are way to many and you know you are not going to use them all you can cache them at least. This will speed up allot

2) is the fact that you do lots of getting an d setting data essentially moving it from 1 place to another. you could do that already before in your request's parseNetworkResponse method. you can infact create the marker there and put them in an array and then on the main thread just iterate to add them to the map.

```
@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(
        NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(response.data,
        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
    return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
    // handle errors
...
}
```

more info from the source [here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html)

Finally even you those 2 things you can still have some problems when you update your map with many markers. The solution to this one is just not to add new markers if you have some already there so you need to keep markers and then just hide and show depending on what the response is. Note that leaving lots of hidden markers will also slow down the map so you will have to clean them at some point.

Comment: thanku for your valuable comment, i have tried your both solutions instead the app getting hanged on some point , can i update my markers by showing some kind of progress bar in front of screen .

Comment: of course you can and you should. there are thousands of solutions and different styles of progress bars/indicators so you have to choose one. basically you need to add it to you layout, then when you make a request you start it and onResponse when the markers are created and ready you stop it :)